# Unity 2D Launch object twards mouse at consistent speed regardless of distance to object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object that I would like to be 'launched' at the mouse position, but depending on the distance of the mouse to the object, the speed will change.

I need a consistent launch speed regardless of distance.

_destination is the mouse position

```
public void GoToDestination(Vector3 _destination)
{   
    //Vector3 rotation = Vector3.
    //Debug.Log("    :" + _destination.x + " " + _destination.y);
    //Debug.Log("Norm:" + _destination.normalized.x + " " + _destination.normalized.y);
    //Vector3 diff = _destination - transform.position;
    //Vector3 flippedDest = new Vector3(diff.x, diff.y, 0);
    //rb.AddForce(flippedDest * speed);
    //Debug.Log(rb.velocity);
    //_destination.y = -_destination.y;
    //_destination = (_destination - transform.position).normalized;
    //rb.velocity = Vector3.Cross(transform.position, _destination) * speed;//(_destination.normalized - transform.position.normalized) * speed;
    //rb.AddForce(_destination * speed);
    //destination = _destination;        
    rb.velocity = (_destination - transform.position).normalized * (speed);
    //destination = _destination;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to convert all Vector3's to Vector2's. The z axis was causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to use distance as a variable for your speed calculation.

I assume this script run on a launched object.

**First thing:**

```
//distance between launched object(transform.position) and mouse position(destination).

 float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destination.position);
```

You can calculate distance on every frame or whatever you want

**Then:**
You have dist variable as a float now . For example if you want to slowdown object when distance become smaller, you can simply multiply with dist like that.

Comment: I want the opposite. I want my object to have the same velocity towards the mouse point no matter how far from the mouse it is.